# Slow USB charging

Tags: usb, charging, samsung-galaxy-s-5

I'm using Samsung Galaxy S5 and usually charge through USB port of Dell Inspiron 14z laptop.
I know that USB charging is slower than wall charging. 
But USB charging becomes much slower than usual recently.

I recently replaced the charging cable and the battery. 
Thus the problem must be in the USB port or the laptop itself.

What could be the reason of this phenomenon and how can I solve it?

Comment: Can you check charging current using "Ampere," app

Comment: @beeshyams I just tried that app and measured several times. It's 800mA. Is this normal?

Comment: @beeshyams After a few miniutes, it drops to 400~500mA.

Comment: USB 3.0 is probably the port you are using on laptop and this gives max 900 mA. As battery gets charged drop in current is to be expected. I am guessing that when you measured battery was around 50%. That's normal. Try cleaning the USB port on device with a blower, Google it. It may help. Otherwise it seems ok

Comment: @beeshyams After a few hours, it now dropped to 300mA. I'll try your suggestion. But the charging is too slow, so I don't think it's normal. With wall charger, it charges approx. 1%/min. But with USB, it never increases.

Comment: That is fine-wall charger is rated at 2 A-twice the USB type 3. Unless you have concrete figures for earlier charging times, it *could* be a bias (I have experienced this- I am not saying you are biased). With *USB it never increases*- are you using the device to play/download/watch videos etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be in the cable itself. Most of the third party cables are not capable enough to transfer enough power to charge a device in a certain period of time. A branded cable may not have this problem. What type of cable did you buy? Have you checked its power specifications before buying it?
Also, I don't think that there is a problem  with the phone's battery. If there was, you would be facing a whole lot of different problem than this one.

Comment: I believe there is no problem with the cable. I bought an authentic cable at Samsung store.